# Comparison of Riemann Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Can idea of convexity/concavity be applied to $$S_{n}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+rn+r^2}$$ and $$T_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+rn+r^2}$$ Here, $$T_{n}=S_{n}+\frac{2}{3n}$$ and the corresponding integral is $$\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$ How to justify that $$S_{n}<\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}<T_{n}$$

Comment: Yes. I have edited.

Comment: Isn't $S_n = T_n + \frac{1}{3n}- \frac{1}{n} = T_n - \frac{2}{3n}$?

Comment: I am sorry. I goofed umpteen number of times. I have edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is only the property that $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}$ being decreasing on the interval $[0,1]$. The $T_{n}$ is the partition $\{[0,1/n],...,[(n-1)/n,1]\}$ taking with left endpoints for each subinterval, and $S_{n}$ the right endpoints.

More rigorously, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}dx&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^{2}}dx\\
&<\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\dfrac{1}{1+(k/n)+(k/n)^{2}}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{2}+kn+k^{2}}\\
&=T_{n},
\end{align*}
similar estimation applies for $S_{n}$.